# Ruby on Rails: Reading from nested parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have these parameters:

```
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"parent_wise_fee_payments", "transaction_date"=>"2015-10-16", "action"=>"pay_payments", "id"=>"10", 
  "transactions"=>{"payment_mode"=>"Cash", 
  "1"=>{"payment_id"=>"54", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "amount"=>"", "parent_id"=>"10", "payment_date"=>"2015-10-16", "title"=>"Second Payment", "payment_note"=>""}, 
  "0"=>{"payment_id"=>"53", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "amount"=>"600000", "parent_id"=>"10", "payment_date"=>"2015-10-16", "title"=>"First Payment", "payment_note"=>""}, 
  "payment_note"=>""}, "authenticity_token"=>"6jbXWEjBnhQjbWpNiK4cCWPhr/NSDEwul6kH+XcKE/U="}
```

The "1", and "0" aren't fixed, they depend on the number of transactions, so I might have for example 3 transactions, each with payment_id, payment_mode, amount, ...

I'm only interested to get the values of each transaction, i.e the values under "1" and "0". But I just can't find a way to do this.

Here's what I tried:

```
  params[:transactions].each do |payment|
        payment.each do |p|
            .... p[0][:amount]
end
end
```

This gives an error, because payment[0] is "payment_mode" which have only 1 value, and payment[1] is "payment_note". I'm unable to access "1" and "0", even when I tried payment["0"]["amount"] and payment["0"][:amount] I got "can't convert string to integer". I also tried using payment.keys to check if the key is "payment_mode" or "payment_note" and discard it, but I got "undefined method keys for array". I'm lost here, and I know I'm messing things up, but I really need your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

The value under the key "transactions" is again a hash, so you need to iterate both value and key.

One way of doing this would be

```
# This works only in rails, not in plain ruby
payments = params["transactions"].except(["payment_mode", "payment_note"])
payments.each do |key, value|
    puts "key: " + key
    puts "values under that key: " + value
end
```

See also
https://repl.it/BRCs/2

In this case, the numbers "0", "1" will be in the variable "key" and the value they're holding in "value".